# Selecting specific data, from a comparison relation, from a file and write it in a list

Tags: python

Basically I am reading different files that contain two columns of values. What I'm trying to do is to get the data pairs, data located in the same row, every increase of a certain value in the second column. The point is that in the second column there are repeated numbers that I would like to avoid. The data is in a .txt file and the columns are separated by an empty space ' '.
The data pairs are similar to: 46.68 255 ;  46.81 226 ;  46.94 225 ; 47.07 225 ; 47.22 225 (but every pair of data is a new row).

So basically if the value of the second column equals 10, column2[i] = 10, I want to get the data pair when the value of the second column equals 10+increase: column2[j] = 10+increase then append column1[j] and column2[j].

```
for filename in txtfiles: 
    X, y_pixel = np.loadtxt(filename, unpack=True, usecols=(0,1))
    var = y_pixel[0]
    goodx, goody = [], []

    for k in range(len(X)):
        if y_pixel[k] <= var+25.:
            var = y[k]
            goody.append(var)
            goodx.append(X[k])
    X, y = np.asarray(goodx), np.asarray(goody)
```

So if it was a list of numbers from 0 to 100, what I would like to get is a list with the numbers: 0 ; 25 ; 50 ; 75 ; 100

And what I am getting now is the whole dataset.

Comment: What is the file format? And how is the data stored in it?

Comment: Yep, so the code dataset is stored in a file ".txt" in two different columns separated by a white space( ' ' )

PD: I wanted to attach an example of the dataset but I couldn't find the option

Comment: you could add them as plain text or something like this. Not all just a few lines

Comment: Just imagine that every pair of data is situated in a new row : 46.68 255
 46.81 226
 46.94 225
 47.07 225
 47.22 225
 47.37 224
 47.55 224
 47.76 224
 47.96 224
 48.09 223
 48.25 223
 48.39 222
 48.56 222
 48.69 221
 48.83 221
 49.02 220
 49.16 220
 49.37 219
 49.50 219
 49.63 218
 49.76 218
 49.98 218
 50.18 217
 50.40 217
 50.57 217
 50.71 217
 50.90 217